# How to find two sets of vectors which satisfy a set of matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

In my trial to solve a system of matrix equations, I wish to find two sets of non-zero vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which may be not unique) $\{ A_i \}$ and $\{ B_i \}$ where $i \in I$ (an index set, with a decomposition $I = I_1 \sqcup I_2$) satisfying
$$
\tag{1} \ \sum_{ i \in I } A_i \otimes B_i - B_i \otimes A_i \ = \ \left( 0\text{-matrix} \right)
$$
$$
\tag{2} \ \sum_{ i \in I_1 } A_i \otimes A_i - B_i \otimes B_i \ = \ \left( \text{Identity-matrix} \right)
$$
$$
\tag{3} \ \sum_{ i \in I_2 } A_i \otimes A_i - B_i \otimes B_i \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \left( \text{Identity-matrix} \right).
$$
where the matrices are $3 \times 3$-matrices, and $\left( A_i \otimes B_i \right)_{ lm }$ ( $l$-th rank and $m$-th column element of the matrix $A_i \otimes B_i$ ) is defined as $\left( A_i \right)_l \left( B_i \right)_m$ ( the multiplication of $l$-th element of vector $A_i$ with $m$-th element of vector $B_i$, where $1 \leq l, m \leq 3$.)

Comment: Do you mean $I = I_1 \sqcup I_2$?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the comment and kind revision.

Comment: What is $\otimes$? Over what ring are the vectors and what is their dimension?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry that I could not have properly informed in the question concerning the dimension.  In my trial, I am considering that the vectors in the left-hand sides are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the matrices in the right-hand sides are $3 \times 3$ ones.  I have tried to revise the question properly.  Thank you for the comment.

Comment: With the obvious basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ of $\mathbb R^3$, $I_1 = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $I_2 = \{1, 2, 3\}$, $A_i = e_i$ for $i \in I_1$, $A_i = \sqrt 2^{-1}e_i$ for $i \in I_2$, and $B_i = 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: Thank you for kind comment.  In my recent trial, I am finding two sets of "non-zero" vectors $A_j$ and $B_j$.  I am sorry that I have just revised the question again with "non-zero" condition.  Two index sets $I_1$ and $I_2$ are a disjoint decomposition of the index set $I$.